# Как получить все заголовки h1 из списка ссылок

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

В переменной `link` функции `get_page_data(html)` находятся ссылки со страниц которых хочу получить все заголовки `h1`. Сейчас парсер получает заголовок последней страницы списка `link`. Как получить список заголовков `h1` со всех страниц из списка `link`?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    ads = soup.find("nav", class_="main-mnu hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs").find("ul").find_all("li")
    for ad in ads:
        urls = ad.find("a").get("href")
        link = "https://gbcrem.by" + urls
        # Печатаем список ссылок
        print(link)

    return link

def get_content(html, links):
    r = requests.get(links)
    # Печатаем ссылки которые возвращает links
    print(r.url)

    return r.text

def get_h_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    page_url = soup.find_all("body", class_="ishome")
    for ad in page_url:
        h = ad.find_all("h1")
        # Печатаем все заголовки h1 для каждой ссылки из списка
        print(h)

def main():

    url = "https://gbcrem.by"

    html = get_html(url)
    get_page_data(html)

    links = get_page_data(html)
    get_content(html, links)

    html = get_content(html, links)
    get_h_content(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из `get_page_data` нужно возвращать список ссылок, а не только последнюю ссылку:

```
def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    links = []

    ads = soup.find("nav", class_="main-mnu hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs").find("ul").find_all("li")
    for ad in ads:
        urls = ad.find("a").get("href")
        link = "https://gbcrem.by" + urls
        # Печатаем список ссылок
        print(link)
        links.append(link)

    return links
```

После пройтись по ссылкам, скачать, распарсить и вытащить из них `h1`:

```
links = get_page_data(html)
for url in links:
    html = get_html(url)
    get_h_content(html)
```

---

**PS.**

Если нужно чтобы функция `get_h_content` возвращала список заголовков, то делайте по аналогии с `get_page_data` – заводите список, заполняйте и возвращайте его